# Leaflet L.DomEvent.On returning an error on marker click

Tags: leaflet, markers

I used two button in my marker popup. I need to trigger a function by clicking on marker. I used the following code. Its working fine. But when I am clicking on marker it's returning an error in console

```
    var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(23.25, 90.56), {
        icon: myIcon,  riseOnHover: true, riseOffset: 25
    });

    map.addLayer(marker);
    var title =  "My Title";
    var subTitle = "My Sub Title";
    var analysisPharam = "Analytical Parameter";
    var popupContent = "<dl>"
        + "<dt class='popup-h1'><b>Title: </b>" + title + "</dt>"
        + "<dt class='subTitle'><b>SubTitle: </b>" + subTitle + "</dt>"
        + "<button id='layerAnalysis' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Analyze</button>"
        + "<button id='popupClose' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Close</button>";
    "</dl>";

    marker.bindPopup(popupContent);

    marker.on('popupopen', function(){
        L.DomEvent.on(
            $("#layerAnalysis").click(function () {
                analysisFunction(analysisPharam);
            })
        );
    });
```

The error in console and the myAction.js indicating error at `L.DomEvent.on` event

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
>     at Object.trim (leaflet.js:5)
>     at Object.splitWords (leaflet.js:5)
>     at Object.on (leaflet.js:6)
>     at e.<anonymous> (myAction.js:487)
>     at e.fire (leaflet.js:5)
>     at e.onAdd (leaflet.js:7)
>     at e._layerAdd (leaflet.js:6)
>     at e.whenReady (leaflet.js:6)
>     at e.addLayer (leaflet.js:6)
>     at e.openPopup (leaflet.js:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    L.DomEvent.on(
        $("#layerAnalysis").click(function () {
            analysisFunction(analysisPharam);
        })
    );
```

That doesn't make any sense.

Check the Leaflet reference to see the parameters to `L.DomEvent.on`. It looks like

> ```
>  on(<HTMLElement> el, <String> types, <Function> fn, <Object> context?)
> ```

So a call needs at least three parameters

- An instance of `HTMLElement`
- A space-separated string of the event names to attach to
- A handler function

e.g.:

```
L.DomEvent.on(
    document.getElementById('layerAnalysis'), // HTMLElement
    'click', // String with event names
    function(ev) { console.log('clicked!') } // Handler function
);
```

Instead of that, you're using [jQuery's `click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to attach an event handler:

```
$('#layerAnalysys')   // jquery selector for one HTML element
   .click(   // Attach a handler to the 'click' event of selected elements
     function(ev) { console.log('clicked!') } // Handler function
   );
```

The return of any jQuery call is a jQuery selector (so `$(foo)` is the same as `$(foo).click(handler)`). You're feeding that to `L.DomEvent.on` (it's wrong! it's not an instance of `HTMLElement` as `L.DomEvent.on` expects!). And obviously, as you're only passing one parameter to `L.DomEvent.on`, it's missing the second and third, and throws some errors around.

---

Read the API documentation for the libraries you're using. Know what each statement in your code should evaluate to. Don't copy-paste code blindly. Understand what it does.